# After how many days should an engagement or marriage be organised after the demise of a family member?

Tags: marriage, death

My grandfather's younger brother's aunt passed away. We want to organise a legal marriage/engagement. So, after how many days can we organise that? It's a non veg engagement.

Comment: As far as I know, If its a traditional Hindu marriage, then there are some rituals that take place 2-3 days before the actual marriage, If they had already been done, then all other rituals should proceed as normal, even in an event of death. Otherwise, it is considered to be either 5th or the 14th day after death to start other activities,  Better to consult a local preist.

Comment: grandfather's younger brother's aunt -> means your "Great Grand Aunt" must be really old.

Comment: The traditions people used to follow will keep on changing with the passage of time.  Further, a tradition being followed by people in one area may not be followed by the people from another area, though all follow Hinduism.  In Ramayana, after performing last rites of King Dasaratha, Bharata was requested by the priests to take over the kingdom.  So customs/traditions will change according to place/time.@Angel Rose.